# On the boundary map of a locally finite chain complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am just learning about locally finite homology and I'm having a bit trouble understanding some of its concepts. There doesn't seem to be a whole lot of (non-advanced) literature on this topic, so I am asking this question here.

If $X$ is a reasonably well-behaved space (in my case, $X$ is always a smooth finite-dimensional manifold), one defines the *locally finite chain complex* $C^{lf}(X)$ of $X$ by declaring $C_r^{lf}(X)$ as the abelian group generated by all formal (infinite) products $\prod_\alpha \sigma_\alpha$, where  $\sigma_\alpha$ a singular $r$-simplex of X and each $x \in X$ has a neighborhood $U$ with the property that the set $\{\alpha: |\sigma_\alpha| \cap U \neq \emptyset \}$ is finite.

In the textbooks I found, it is simply stated that the boundary map $\partial_r: C_r^{lf}(X) \to C_{r-1}^{lf}(X)$ is the usual one for singular chains. I find this a bit confusing for the following reason:
On $C_r(X)$, the group of *singular r-chains*, one usually defines that boundary map $\partial_r: C_r(X) \to C_{r-1}(X)$ by declaring the image of $\partial_r$ on the standard *basis* of $C_r(X)$, consisting of all singular $r$-simplices of $X$. However, one cannot do the same thing on $C_r^{lf}(X)$, as this group is *not* free abelian whenever $X$ is not a finite set. Therefore, I wonder

*How would one rigorously define the boundary map $\partial_r: C_r^{lf}(X) \to C_{r-1}^{lf}(X)$?*

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of infinite products you should use infinite sums. Then simply define
$$
\partial \sum_{\alpha} c_\alpha \sigma_\alpha := \sum_{\alpha} c_\alpha \partial \sigma_\alpha 
$$
for each locally finite infinite sum.

Comment: The key point that needs to be checked here is that the right-hand side of this equation is well-defined, i.e. no simplex appears infinitely many times in that sum and the result is locally finite.

Comment: Which can be checked easily since the left-hand side is locally finite. I think my problem was not realizing that one doesnt necessarily need the set of singular r-simplices to be a basis for the boundary map to be well-defined. The only thing thats important is that each element has a unique expression in terms of those simplices, and it does not matter if this expression is infinite, as long as it is locally finite